# Unable to reference local variable in-line assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am unable to compile a contract that references a local variable in in-line assembly.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

/**
 * @dev Contract module that helps prevent reentrant calls to a function.
 *
 * Inheriting from `ReentrancyGuard` will make the {nonReentrant} modifier
 * available, which can be applied to functions to make sure there are no nested
 * (reentrant) calls to them.
 *
 * Note that because there is a single `nonReentrant` guard, functions marked as
 * `nonReentrant` may not call one another. This can be worked around by making
 * those functions `private`, and then adding `external` `nonReentrant` entry
 * points to them.
 *
 * TIP: If you would like to learn more about reentrancy and alternative ways
 * to protect against it, check out our blog post
 * https://blog.openzeppelin.com/reentrancy-after-istanbul/[Reentrancy After Istanbul].
 *
 * _Since v2.5.0:_ this module is now much more gas efficient, given net gas
 * metering changes introduced in the Istanbul hardfork.
 */
contract ReentrancyGuard {
    /// Address of lock flag variable.
    /// Flag is placed at random memory location to not interfere with Storage contract.
    uint constant private LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS = 0x8e94fed44239eb2314ab7a406345e6c5a8f0ccedf3b600de3d004e672c33abf4; // keccak256("ReentrancyGuard") - 1;

    function initializeReentrancyGuard () internal {
        // Storing an initial non-zero value makes deployment a bit more
        // expensive, but in exchange the refund on every call to nonReentrant
        // will be lower in amount. Since refunds are capped to a percetange of
        // the total transaction's gas, it is best to keep them low in cases
        // like this one, to increase the likelihood of the full refund coming
        // into effect.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 1) }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Prevents a contract from calling itself, directly or indirectly.
     * Calling a `nonReentrant` function from another `nonReentrant`
     * function is not supported. It is possible to prevent this from happening
     * by making the `nonReentrant` function external, and make it call a
     * `private` function that does the actual work.
     */
    modifier nonReentrant() {
        bool notEntered;
        assembly { notEntered := sload(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS) }

        // On the first call to nonReentrant, _notEntered will be true
        require(notEntered, "ReentrancyGuard: reentrant call");

        // Any calls to nonReentrant after this point will fail
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 0) }

        _;

        // By storing the original value once again, a refund is triggered (see
        // https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2200)
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 1) }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
use experimental features on live deployments.
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
^-------------------------------^

IEIP1271.sol:13:3: TypeError: Function overload clash during conversion to external types for arguments.
  function isValidSignature(
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:34:27: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 1) }
                          ^---------------^

generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:46:40: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { notEntered := sload(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS) }
                                       ^---------------^

generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:52:27: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 0) }
                          ^---------------^

generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:58:27: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 1) }
                          ^---------------^

dev-contracts/generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:34:27: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 1) }
                          ^---------------^

dev-contracts/generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:46:40: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { notEntered := sload(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS) }
                                       ^---------------^

dev-contracts/generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:52:27: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 0) }
                          ^---------------^

dev-contracts/generated/ReentrancyGuard.sol:58:27: TypeError: Constant variables not supported by inline assembly.
        assembly { sstore(LOCK_FLAG_ADDRESS, 1) }
                          ^---------------^

Error: Compilation failed
    at processOutput (/Users/samueldare/Documents/Code/brave/zksync/contracts/node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/compiler/dist/cjs/compiler.js:36:15)
    at compileAndSave (/Users/samueldare/Documents/Code/brave/zksync/contracts/node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/compiler/dist/cjs/compiler.js:17:11)
```

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Your contract compiles fine on solc 0.6.12.

Comment: And also on 0.5.13.

Comment: Thanks!! The issue is that 0.5.0 does not allow access local variables from in line assembly. Bumped it up to 0.5.11 and it works